# How can I get the correct DisplayMetrics from an AppWidget in Android?

Tags: android, resources, android-widget, android-appwidget

I need to determine the screen density at runtime in an Android AppWidget.  I've set up an HDPI emulator device (avd).  If set up a regular executable project, and insert this code into the onCreate method:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
Log.d("MyTag", "screen density " + dm.densityDpi);
```

This outputs "screen density 240" as expected.

However, if I set up an AppWidget project, and insert this code into the onUpdate method:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
Log.d("MyTag", "screen density " + dm.densityDpi);
```

This outputs "screen density 160".  I noticed, hooking up the debugger, that the mDefaultDisplay member of the Resources object here is null in the AppWidget case.

Similarly, if I get a resource at runtime using the Resources object obtained from context.getResources() in the AppWidget, it returns the wrong resource based on screen density.  For instance, I have a 60x60px drawable for mdpi, and an 80x80 drawable for hdpi.  If I get this Drawable object using context.getResources().getDrawable(...), it returns the 60x60 version.

Is there any way to correctly deal with resources at runtime from the context of an AppWidget?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feels like a bug. If you can create a sample project that demonstrates the error, post an issue on the [Android issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list). If you think of it, add a comment here pointing to the issue.

Comment: Hmmm.  I created a simple widget to do nothing but demonstrate this bug, and it correctly displays 240 in the HDPI emulator device.  I'll go back and try to figure out what's different about my other widget.  Thanks for looking.

Comment: Aha.  I was missing the <uses-sdk> tag in my manifest.  If I set the min sdk version to to anything >= 4 I get the correct screen density at runtime.