# How to use whole screen on 1024x480 Android device (Acer Iconia Smart)?

Tags: user-interface, screen, android

When running manually compiled Android apps on the Acer Iconia Smart, there always remains a black bar at the bottom of the screen that is not usable by the apps. This happens for my own as well as other apps compiled from source. Pre-installed apps do not show this behavior and make use of the whole screen.

The device has a 1024x480 screen, but I can only make use of 855×480 pixels. This is the size reported by `getResources().getDisplayMetrics()`.

So far, any attempts to fix the issue have failed, including:

- manually changing the display metrics (using `getResources().updateConfiguration(config, metrics)`.
- setting all possible attributes of `<supports-screens>` to `true` in the Android manifest.

`android:minSdkVersion` is set to `10`, corresponding to the Android 2.3.3 version on the device.

Any ideas? Did anybody successfully deploy self-compiled apps on this device that make use of the entire screen estate?

Comment: Not sure if this is an answer or not, but... http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html "By default, a modern application (using API Level 4 or higher) supports all screen sizes; older applications are assumed to support only the "normal" screen size." Check your API version? Also 'By default, the system will resize your application to fill the screen, if you have set either `minSdkVersion` or `targetSdkVersion` to "4" or higher.' So maybe check that too?

Comment: @JAB Thanks. mindSdkVersion is already set to 10. I have edited the question in that regard.

Comment: @ot: Just found a potentially related question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643198/how-can-i-get-the-correct-displaymetrics-from-an-appwidget-in-android And then I noticed that http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html has a slightly method of getting the display metrics than the method you're using. Perhaps your problem is related to that?

Comment: @JAB I have tried this, but the metrics obtained this way are the same (actually 855x480, and not 800x480 as reported before).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following line to the application's Android manifest makes the entire screen available:

```
 <uses-feature android:name="com.acer.android.XLONG_SCREEN" 
               android:required="false" />
```